# Change text when file attached

Tags: jquery

I want change text, when i check file and want to submit form. This is my form

```
    $(" #client-form input[type='file'], .webform-client-form input[type='file'], #contact-form input[type='file']").click(function() {
    $(this).change(function(){
        $('p.pull-left > span').text('Attached');
    });
});
```

I have check for input with type text. If it's valid, i remove border and in this moment my action work and change my text on "Attached" but i don't click on this field and doesn't attache anything. Please, help me

Comment: Why the need for the `click()` event handler? Do `change()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) directly instead of binding for the `.click()` event:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#client-form input[type=file], .webform-client-form input[type=file], #contact-form input[type=file]').on('change', function() {
         $('p.pull-left > span').text('Attached');
    });

});
```

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes.